# How to go about implementing pathfinding in Unity with Tiled2Unity map prefabs?

Tags: 2d, unity, path-finding, tiled, tiles

I have created a map using `Tiled` application and have added collision boxes and used Tiled2Unity to import the map to Unity. The collisions are working with key inputs.

I want to implement pathfinding in my 2D tile game.

I have studied and written a A * pathfinding code with 2D array in C#, which is working. But with the map import I have no way to iterate through the tiles.

How to go about implementing pathfinding?